# Почему дают "на чай"?

Tags: фразеология

Официантам оставляют "на чай" или "чаевые". А почему именно на чай и зачем он официантам?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не только официантам. Вообще всякой прислуге. А в советское время - чуть ли любому работнику службы быта.

Вообще "на чай" появилось в прямом значении. Чай был напитком достаточно дорогим и престижным. А чайные - неким аналогом современных клубов. Поэтому дать швейцару или посыльному "на чай" было довольно высоким материальным поощрением. Кроме того, если память не подводит, "на чай" выдавали отдельной статьей расходов наемным работникам, командируемым и, кажется, даже солдатам и унтер-офицерам. Отсюда и "чаевые", которое потом несколько изменило значения.